# Quartz.net thread pool size does not correspond to running jobs count

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

While setting thread pool size 10 (or default) in Simple thread pool implementation, I cannot get more the two jobs running at the same time.

When the thread pool size is set to 100, I can get many jobs running concurrently (tried about 15).

How is it possible that thread pool size of 10 does not correspond to 10 concurrent jobs?

Do some components of Quartz.Net (listeners, triggers) eat threads out of threadpool? Or is it possible that multiple threads are used up by a single job?

Comment: How long does the jobs take to complete?

Comment: It seems that setting the thread pool size to 100 didnt help either...

Jobs can take anywhere in between a few seconds to few hours, how does that refer to threads from thread pool being used up?

Comment: I had a similar discussion with a developer just last week and he wondered why his threadpool only ever used one thread. His jobs completed before his loop could submit another one, that's why I asked. I'll butt out of this since this is not your issue, best of luck :)

Comment: I see, this is definitely not the case. I can see lots of jobs being misfired.